# :hover malfunction on Mobile Nav Bar

Tags: hover, navbar, display

I am having trouble getting my :hover to work on my mobile nav bar, it isn't allowing me to hide/show my links when the user is hovering over the nav bar.

What I want is when you hover over the green section on the top of the page, the links to all of the seperate pages should show up below it, however, I can't get them to hide themselves when the user isn't hovering over the green section anymore. I've tried placing the hover on different elements and using different kinds of displays, but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code:

**CSS:**

```
#menu {
  background-color: rgb(168, 191, 79);
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  z-index: 2;
}



#menu ul li a:hover {
  color:rgb(168, 191, 79);         

}

#menu ul li a:hover {
  display: block;
}

#menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;

}

#menu ul li a {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgb(70, 94, 125);
  color:white;
  font-family: "eds-market-regular", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 0px;

}

#menu p {
display: inline-block;
color:white;
font-family: "dovetail-mvb", serif;
font-weight: 900;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 24px;
padding-left: 10px; 
margin: 48px 0px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu">

      <img src="images/MenuIcon.png" alt="Hamburger Menu Icon" id="HamIcon">
      <p>Chop Chop Yard Care</p>
      
    
      <ul>

        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>


      </ul>

</div>
```

Here is a link to my website (Shrink Browser to display mobile nav bar):

**file:///C:/Users/User/Downloads/Documents/Se1400/milestone5/contact.html**